# Queries on InternetGetConnectedState

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using `InternetGetConnectedState()` to know, which connection is on.

I have both LAN and wireless modem connected on my system, but this function returns me that only LAN is connected.

Why is this? And how to solved this?

Answer (score 2):

What does your actual code look like?  Are you taking into account that InternetGetConnectedState() returns a bitmask that can contain multiple values at one time?